# What's a Rails plugin, or Ruby gem, to automatically fix English grammar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Facebook just re-launched Comments, with a automatic grammar fixing feature.

> What does the grammar filter do?
>
> - Adds punctuation (e.g. periods at the end of sentences)
> - Trims extra whitespace Auto cases words (e.g. capitalize the first word of a
>     sentence)
> - Expands slang words (e.g. plz becomes please)
> - Adds a space
>     after punctuation (e.g. Hi,Cat would become Hi, Cat)
> - Fix common
>     grammar mistakes (e.g. convert ‘dont' to ‘don’t’)

What is an equivalent plugin or gem?

Comment: None of those things have anything to do with grammar. Terribly named feature.

Comment: @kindall: If forgetting a period not bad grammar, what is it?

Comment: I wouldn't mind such a filter applying to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Period at the end of a sentence" punctuation, not grammar. Also just noticed some of things Facebook claims to fix are mutually exclusive: can't BOTH add periods at end of sentences and ALSO capitalize first letter of sentence. How know where end of sentence was without one or other? (Not to mention, not all capitals begin a sentence and not all periods end one.) Facebook claiming sci-fi level computer understanding of English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of anything with those particular features.

However, you might look at [Ruby LinkParser](http://deveiate.org/projects/Ruby-LinkParser), which is a Ruby wrapper for the Link Grammar parser developed by academics and used by the [Abiword project](http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/) for grammar checking.  (Note that "link" in Link Grammer parser doesn't refer to HTML links, but rather to a structure that describes English syntax as a set of links between words).

Here's another [interesting checker](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nspring/software/style-check-readme.html), written in Ruby, which is designed to check LaTex files for some of the problems you mention (plus others).

Comment: Thanks! Those are great resources, definitely looks like the closest match.

Answer (score 1):

"After the Deadline" is a complete (free) grammar checking service.  Someone has already written a Ruby wrapper for it.

https://github.com/msepcot/after_the_deadline

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Gingerice](https://github.com/subosito/gingerice) which seems to do what you are looking for!